# How to close new terminal forcefully from script, when Profile Preferences are -> Command-> When commands exits:->Hold the terminal open

Tags: shell, process

I'm trying to open two new terminals and run .sh files on them from an script, but after finishing all the commands, I want one terminal to be closed. I'm using `gnome-terminal -e  "sh patterns.sh";`command to open new terminal and to run script.

Comment: But everything seems to go just fine?   Status 0 means "OK".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but then what do I have to do, if I need to close the terminals by command. I'm writing "gnome-terminal -e  "sh patterns.sh"; exit", but it is not working.

Comment: Then why did you choose "Hold the terminal open"??

Comment: Because, most of the time I need the terminal to be opened but few times I need it to be closed, varies with script, so is there any way to forcefully close the terminal by command, while preferences are the same "hold..."?

Answer (score 0):

with the following command, you're killing gnome-terminal:

```
kill $PPID
```

I tried it with xterm, haven't got gnome.

```
 xterm -hold -e "/temp/test.sh; ps -fp \$PPID; sleep 5; kill \$PPID"
```

This is how it works with gnome-terminal:

```
gnome-terminal -e '/bin/ksh -c "/temp/test.sh; kill $PPID"'
```

Comment: I did try kill -9 $PPID earlier and kill $PPID at this time at the end of the script, but the same response "The child process exited normally with status 0, Relaunch ".

Comment: I didn't mean for you to put that command inside the script, but rather `gnome-terminal -e "sh pattern.sh; kill $PPID"

Comment: Yeah that's what I did "gnome-terminal -e  "sh patterns.sh"; kill $PPID", inside the script which are loading the new terminals.

Comment: Sorry!  Should have been `gnome-terminal -e "sh pattern.sh; kill \$PPID" `.  Subtle, but a large difference.

Comment: Actually I've tried "gnome-terminal -e  "sh patterns.sh"; kill \$PPID;" and 17828 as PPID of patterns.sh to kill child process, but its staying after completing its task with "The child process exited normally with status 0.",  but I'm getting error (on the terminal from where I'm running sh script.sh)  "kill: $PPID: arguments must be process or job IDs". I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: `"gnome-terminal -e "sh patterns.sh"; kill \$PPID;"` is not the same as `gnome-terminal -e "sh pattern.sh; kill \$PPID"`.  Can you spot the difference?   It's no use throwing in some double quotes here and there.

Comment: My mistake, couldn't think of this way while asking. That was supposed to mean to differentiate the coding part from context. I used gnome-terminal -e "sh patterns.sh"; kill \$PPID; , rather than gnome-terminal -e "sh pattern.sh; kill \$PPID", because its causing me error (The child process exited normally with status 127.), and when i relaunched the terminal, it's showing (sh: pattern.sh;: No such file or directory) every time.

Comment: Perhaps I dropped an "s"?  `gnome-terminal -e "sh patterns.sh; kill \$PPID"`

Comment: yeah, but I wrote that command by myself, so I corrected that. And I again rechecked it, it's displaying the error, but with my way it runs fine, without "No such.." error, but its not closing the terminal.

Comment: Of course not, gnoeme-terminal should execute the "kill \$PPID", not you.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: what is the full path of patterns.sh ?

Comment: Both the script I'm running on new terminal, and the script from where I'm opening new terminal are in home/main directory.

Comment: Then specify that path. `gnome-terminal -e "/home/main/patterns.sh; kill \$PPID"`.

Comment: gnome-terminal -e "/home/mayank/patterns.sh; kill \$PPID" is showing - There was an error creating the child process for this terminal, Failed to execute child process "/home/mayank/patterns.sh;" (No such file or directory)

Comment: What is the first line of patterns.sh ?   One last try `gnome-terminal -e "sh /home/main/patterns.sh; kill \$PPID"`

Comment: Its #!/bin/bash and then in second line it asks for MAX no. , and gnome-terminal -e "sh /home/mayank/patterns.sh; kill \$PPID" showed The child process exited normally with status 127, sh: /home/mayank/patter..., No such... .

Comment: So /bin/bash does not exist on your system?   The bang (#!) should say which program is needed to run the script.  It should of course exist.

Comment: Executable file(bash) exists in bin.

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to get gnome-terminal running.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: yeah it actually closed the terminals, but all which were there. Not only patterns.sh one.  gnome-terminal -e '/bin/ksh -c "sh patterns.sh; kill $PPID"'

Comment: I know, I'm good.  So, all terminals belong to a single proces.  What escape sequence is needed to close a single terminal window?

Comment: Yes you are agreed, how can I achieve, only terminal closed whose PPID I kill by command and other remain same.

Comment: `gnome-terminal -e '/bin/ksh -c "/temp/test.sh $PPID; sleep 3; xdotool key --clearmodifiers shift+control+A"'`   "shift+control+A" is in fact a "shift+control+Q", but I have an azerty keyboard, the A is where the Q is on a qwerty keyboard.

Comment: Hi @Gerard sorry for late response, thank you for this command, it's working fine but it hangs my system,  and sometime new terminal stays with "The child process exited normally with status 0". And sometime it closes all the terminals, but when it does work fine, I'm not able to perform anything on the main terminal.